# Visual Basic Search for a keyword, add new word to adjacent column

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to search events data for a keyword, let's say an Apple.  Within my data set there are likely hundreds.  I then need excel to put the word RED in the column to the left of each successful find.  Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: VB.NET, or VBA?

Answer (score 0):

below formula should help

```
=IF(FIND("I get",E9,1)>0,"RED")
```

IF condition results in putting word "RED" when a search string is found in the target cell *(E9) in this example*

FIND searches for the string of interest *("I get" in this example)* in the given cell and returns position of the string.

You may Copy down this formula to the entire range of the column where you like to see RED (Select cells in column and press CTRL+D)

Hope this helps

Comment: The option provided above is an incell macro (and not VBA macro).... If you go in the option of incell macro, you would copy the formula provided above as is in the cell F5 to display "RED" if your search string is found in cell G5 of worksheet with index 1

Comment: Srinvas this is perfect thank you.  One more question, lets say, within the same search I need to check for another string also.  So like you put above I get is going to be RED, but if I get isn't in there and let's say I KNOW is and that should be ORANGE, how would I define this?